# Best way to keep Heroku awake with 1 dyno

Tags: ruby, heroku, puma

What the best solution to keeping a Heroku app alive whilst keeping with the 1 dyno?

It's a very small application, but rather than the 20-second wait to bring the dyno to life, it would be great if something would ping my Heroku app every 30-or-so minutes to prevent it from going to sleep, which it does every hour.

Some solutions on the web have suggested "New Relic", but I wanted to ask this myself and see if there's a new 2014 answer to a burning question.

Little info: I'm running a middleman app, using Puma on Heroku.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this by using NewRelic.  In my opinion, it's a win/win because you'll get app monitoring of your site plus keeping the site awake.

Other alternatives would be to write a cron job on a separate machine which pings your site once an hour.  This would mean you'd need to have another machine up and alive to do this work, but it's an option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've done exactly this and seems to be working well. The suggested duplicate does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Not a duplicate as the other answer only lists one possible way to do this. Hasty.